# NAS connectivity setup with wireless router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, nas

I am looking forward to buy a NAS device. However I have some issues regarding the network/setup. I get internet from a wireless router, which gets in the house somewhere on a typical ADSL connector, and it has a very nice spot on a shelf. The phone company has a very well defined entry point in the house for the network cable, which is the furthest possible from where I want to put the NAS box. I don't want to have 20 meters of cables running around the house, it will be ugly... So, the question:

How can I setup the NAS box using the only existing wireless router (regardless that I could draw 20 meters of network cable from the wireless router to the location of the NAS -> I don't want this) in the house... I'm not aware of any NAS which has a WiFi connectivity (at least the one I plan to use (http://www.komplett.no/k/ki.aspx?sku=639215) has nothing like that. What other hardware will I need to make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: You should investigate where your ADSL modem is located. The modem can connect to any phone jack, although that then requires every phone to use a filter. If the phone company has not installed the ADSL modem at the NID and split the line, then you might be able to simply relocate the ADSL modem to a convenient location for the NAS

Comment: To get an idea of how slow your proposed wireless NAS setup would be, use another PC in place of the NAS.  Then perform a PC to PC file transfer over two wireless hops.  I'd guess that you could not play HD videos even with 802.11n links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a wifi-to-ethernet bridge (I won't post any examples as shopping advice is prohibited on stackexchange).  I will point out however that your NAS has gigabit ethernet so you'll be severely crippling it's capabilities by using it over wifi.